# No wifi in ubuntu 20.04 lts (I have tried everything, please help)

Tags: wireless, 20.04, realtek

Good day, I have an Asus laptop that came with a realtek rtl8821ce network card. iwconfig shows l0: no wireless extensions. I dont know what else to do. Someone please help me.

I am not able to list all the things I have tried unfortunately, but some are below:

1. Tried restarting network manager
2. Tried clean installs of Ubuntu 20.04
3. Tried using a compatibility layer and installing windows drivers
4. Re-installed/updated drivers
5. Changed the network card
6. Disabled secure boot

System info from inxi:

- System:
  Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
- Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: VivoBook_ASUS Laptop E210MA_L210MA
  v: 1.0 serial: 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: E210MA v: 1.0 serial: 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: E210MA.306 date: 10/29/2020
- Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 34.0 Wh condition: 36.3/38.0 Wh (95%)
  model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery status: Charging
- CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron N4020 bits: 64 type: MCP
  arch: Goldmont Plus rev: 8 L2 cache: 4096 KiB
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 4377
  Speed: 796 MHz min/max: 800/2800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 830 2: 868
- Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 605 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel
  bus ID: 00:02.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: i915 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6
  direct render: Yes
- Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
  bus ID: 00:0e.0
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-50-generic
- Network:
  Message: No Device data found.
  IF-ID-1: usb0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac:
- Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 58.24 GiB used: 7.65 GiB (13.1%)
  ID-1: /dev/mmcblk0 model: DA4064 size: 58.24 GiB
- Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 56.58 GiB used: 7.65 GiB (13.5%) fs: ext4
  dev: /dev/mmcblk0p2
- Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0
- Info:
  Processes: 204 Uptime: 2h 34m Memory: 3.67 GiB used: 1.70 GiB (46.3%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Shell: bash v: 5.0.17
  inxi: 3.0.38

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123721/discussion-on-question-by-drdmck-no-wifi-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-i-have-tried-every).